# JDBC подключение к oracle

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

Не могу подключится к базе oracle

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
Connection connection = null;
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","dima","123456");
connection.close();
```

Вылетает Exception, никак не могу разобраться как правильно указать url адрес

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-12705: Cannot access NLS data files or invalid environment specified

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:447)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:389)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:382)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.processError(T4CTTIfun.java:675)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.processError(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:448)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:513)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:227)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:383)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:776)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:432)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:553)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:254)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:528)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at ru.mypackage.databaseConnection.Main.main(Main.java:20)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Oracle установлен на локальном сервере

Connection name - MyServerConnection 
Connection details - dima@//localhost:1521/xe

Comment: попробуйте добавь перед открытием соединения:
'Locale.setDefault(Locale.ENGLISH);'

Comment: Теперь все прекрасно работает! Спасибо! А почему возникла такая проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ORA-12705 обычно происходит, когда Oracle выполняет автоматический «alter session» во время входа в систему и обнаруживает недопустимую настройку NLS_LANG.

Возможны две причины:

- Была сделана попытка выдать инструкцию ALTER SESSION с недопустимым параметром или значением NLS.
- Переменная среды NLS_LANG содержит недопустимый язык, территорию или набор символов.

Рекомендуют удалить или переименовать этот параметр из реестра 
Для ошибок ORA-12705, вызванных недействительными настройками NLS_LANG, вам необходимо убедиться, что он «не установлен» \HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE. Но так делать я не рекомендую.